# What control flow suits "if A, then do a; if B, then do a, b; if C, then do a, b, c ..."

Tags: java, python, c, control-flow

In C, the cascade switch statement can be used to easily implement this flow:

```
switch (var) {
    case c: C();
    case b: B();
    case a: A();
    default: // no op
}
```

Are there alternatives to support this flow in other programming languages? E.g. in Python, Java?

Comment: Java has identical `switch` statement. You already wrote legal Java.

Comment: Unfortunately ..... :-)

Comment: I don't get this question. It's way to broad. What defines an acceptable answer? Is it a game of coming up with a rosetta-code page demonstrating this simple snippet in as many languages as possible?

Comment: A literal answer to the question is, "yes, there are.".

Comment: @StephenC why "unfortunately"? This is a tool and like any other tool, it can be used to great effect or very badly.

Comment: In any lambda-blessed language you can get the same behavior with a list of lambdas and a mapping from the case label to the appropriate list index. Then you just evaluate the tail of the list starting at the index. But that's mostly beside the point because `switch` is primarily about optimization, not cool and practical semantics.

Comment: I think your code fails to match your title. The code says: "If a, do A(), B(), C(), if b, do B(), C(), if c, do C()."

Comment: @fge In a language designed for simplicity one may legitimately raise that objection. `switch` must have been left in as a nod to all the C devs switching to Java.

Comment: @fge - The problems are 1) accidental drop through is a source of errors, 2) *in the vast majority of cases* you don't want the drop through, and hence the `break` to stop the drop through is tantamount to syntactic noise.

Comment: This code doesn't do what the title says: It does "If A, do a; if B, do b, a; if C, do c, b, a".

Comment: @JeremyWest will edit

Comment: @StephenC well, like I said... Fall through is actually very powerful, but like all powerful tools, you must be careful not to misuse! It's just like `goto` (which Java doesn't have anyway).

Comment: @fge: I agree that fall-through is a feature, although (if C were redesigned from scratch today) I would prefer it wasn't the default (say, you must use `continue;` to request it explicitly). Btw, Java has those cool `break label;` and `continue label;` statements, which are a "cleaner `goto`", IMO.

Comment: @mafso even those are not a replacement for a "real" goto :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can support that flow in any language that has `if` statements, and a logical OR operator (which would be all of them)

```
flow = 0;

if ( var == a ) {
   A();
   flow = 1;
}

if ( flow || var == b ) {
   B();
   flow = 1;
}

if ( flow || var == c ) {
   C();
   flow = 1;
}

// and so on
```